# Redirect classes to a remote location in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

I am using eclipse 3.2 in windows environment. I have deployed the webserver in Solaris environment. I want to redirect the class files to the WEB-INF/ folder of the web server in Solaris. I tried using the RSE plug-in of the eclipse. I could see and access the files using the remote explorer but could not transer / redirect the class files from the package explorer to the  webserver location. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you can mount the remote directory as a local drive (which I'm not sure you can do), you can use the [FileSync](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/filesync/index.html) plugin and set it up so that the files are copied from your /bin to the remote dir.

Another option is to use the commercial MyEclipse. Actually, WTP might have an option for remote deployment, of which I'm unaware.

But I would advice against such a thing, if the target server is something more than a development server. Better use a Continuous Integration engine (Hudson), together with maven/ant.